# Swift to Objective-C call with trailing closure calls wrong method

Tags: objective-c, swift

Given the following Objective-C methods

```
@import Foundation;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TestClass : NSObject
// Variant 1. Notice that arg1 is nullable, and that all closure arguments are nullable.
+ (void)test:(NSString *_Nullable)arg1
                 action:(nullable void (^)(void))action;

// Variant 2. Notice that arg2 is non null, there is an additional, nullable, closure argument
+ (void)test:(NSString *)title
      action:(nullable void (^)(void))action
     action2:(nullable void (^)(void))action2;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

I find that when I attempt to call the first method from Swift with fully specified args, it actually calls the second variant when I use a trailing closure

```
// Calls first variant (This is an erroneous claim, hence Matt's answer)
TestClass.test("arg1", action: {})

// Calls second variant
TestClass.test("arg2") {}
```

I was expecting Variant 1 to be called in both cases. I'm unclear if I'm doing something wrong or not. I also seem to have missed the fact that Swift could provide generate arguments at all when calling Obj-C methods and am struggling to find the relevant documentation on it.

If I replace the Obj-C TestClass with the equivalent

```
class TestClass {
    class func test(_ arg1: String?, action: (() -> ())? = nil) {
        
    }

    class func test(_ arg1: String!, action: (() -> ())? = nil, action2: (() -> ())? = nil) {
        // Should not get here
        assert(false)
    }

}
```

Then I get a compiler warning about ambiguous use of 'test' in both calls.

Tested on Xcode 12.3 and 12.4.

Comment: From a Swift perspective, the resolution of these two methods is somewhat ambiguous (or at best, relies on unobvious rules) if you don’t supply an `action2`. I wouldn’t worry about how Swift resolves this and would instead change the interface to be unambiguous (to both the compiler and to humans reading the code). E.g., if you can, make `action2` in the second method to not be `nullable`, then the ambiguity is resolved. (Are there really times that you need the second method with `action2` parameter where you wouldn’t supply an `action2`?)

Comment: Pragmatically, I can simply refactor. There's no question that the existing code is badly named (obviously the code I posted above is a test case, not the real code). But I find that I learn the most interesting things from chasing down bugs to their root causes, so I am keen to find out what the Swift method resolution rules are and how they are applied in this case.

Comment: Should point that there are zero compiler warnings. Obvious Obj-C compilation wouldn't generate one - it's not ambiguous as far as it's concerned. It's only Swift using (apparently) auto-generated default parameters when bridging to Obj-C that makes it so. I suppose ultimately that might be the best answer  - don't use trailing closures  when bridging.

Comment: Are you sure you are testing correctly? In my testing we get the second variant in both cases.

Comment: @Rob (Matt is correct) Do you have any objection to deleting this question. I think  it serves no value to keep it.

Comment: @matt do you have any objection to me deleting this question?

Comment: In theory you can do whatever you like in that regard. Personally I'd be a bit miffed, as I put in quite a bit of time and effort investigating this. Also I think the question is quite interesting; the business of what happens when you have two trailing closures with a default value remains contentious in the Swift community.

Comment: That's why I asked. I wasn't sure whether there was value in retaining it given the flaw in my question. In practice, not only is there value in the continued thread of answers, there is even now value in the thread of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously, I expect Variant 1 to be called in both cases.

Actually, I find that Variant 2 is called in both cases.

First generate the Swift interface for your Objective-C interface. You get this:

```
open class func test(_ arg1: String?, action: (() -> Void)? = nil)
open class func test(_ title: String, action: (() -> Void)?, action2: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

We have now eliminated the Objective-C component from the story and can just use these methods in our testing:

```
typealias VoidVoid = () -> Void
func test(_ arg1: String?, action: VoidVoid? = nil) { print("1") }
func test(_ title: String, action: VoidVoid?, action2: VoidVoid? = nil) { print("2") }
func f() {
    test("arg1", action: {})
    test("arg2") {}
}
```

If we call `f()`, the console prints "2" twice. I don't get any compile error, but it does appear that the first variant is unreachable unless you omit *both* function arguments.

Comment: You are, of course, quite right. I don't know how I managed to think that the first variant was being called. I'd blame being ill, but I think that I just rushed to conclusions. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

In matt’s answer, he shared his experience where the compiler would resolve both Swift calls to the second Objective-C variant of the method (the one with the `action2` parameter). We should note that this behavior is unique to the fact that the two methods have a different nullability for the first argument, being an nullable in the first variant, and not nullable in the second variant.

Switch the nullability of the first parameter of the two methods, and the behavior changes, favoring the first variant. Likewise, if both of the renditions use the same nullability, then, again, the first variant will be used. Consider:

```objectivec
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TestClass : NSObject

+ (void)test:(NSString * _Nullable)title
      action:(nullable void (^)(void))action;

+ (void)test:(NSString * _Nullable)title
      action:(nullable void (^)(void))action
     action2:(nullable void (^)(void))action2;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

That this translates to the following Swift interface:

```swift
open class TestClass : NSObject {
    open class func test(_ title: String?, action: (() -> Void)? = nil)    
    open class func test(_ title: String?, action: (() -> Void)?, action2: (() -> Void)? = nil)
}
```

Now, both Swift calls will call the first variant, not the second:

```swift
TestClass.test("foo", action: {}) // variant 1
TestClass.test("foo") {}          // variant 1
```

In your example (where the first variant made the first argument nullable, but the second variant did not), it is resolving to the second variant because we passed a non-optional string.

Given that (hopefully) the first variant is just an Objective-C convenience method to the second variant, it probably does not matter which is called, but the moral of the story is that the resolution to the appropriate Objective-C method is subject to very subtle considerations that may not be obvious at a glance.

---

At the risk of premature optimization, if you really are concerned about ensuring that Swift always call the second Objective-C variant regardless of the nullability/optionality of the first parameter in these two variations, one could make the intent explicit with `NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT` as discussed in [Improving Objective-C API Declarations for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/improving_objective-c_api_declarations_for_swift). For example:

```objectivec
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TestClass : NSObject

+ (void)test:(NSString * _Nullable)title
      action:(nullable void (^)(void))action NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;

+ (void)test:(NSString * _Nullable)title
      action:(nullable void (^)(void))action
     action2:(nullable void (^)(void))action2 NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And then manually declare your own explicit Swift interface:

```swift
extension TestClass {
    @inlinable
    static func test(_ title: String? = nil, action: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        __test(title, action: action, action2: nil)
    }

    @inlinable
    static func test(_ title: String? = nil, action: (() -> Void)?, action2: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        __test(title, action: action, action2: action2)
    }
}
```

That will always call the second variant of the Objective-C method. This eliminates method resolution behaviors that might be otherwise not be obvious, making your intent explicit.

Comment: Unfortunately, comments like "this is totally awesome" are frowned on. Otherwise I'd be saying "this is totally awesome".

Comment: Agreed! This is a good analysis and introduces to me to NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT